# How to read data into Raspberry Pi using modbus-tk?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, modbus, rs485, modbus-tk

So I'm doing a project where I want my Raspberry Pi 4 to communicate through Modbus. I've bought a [shield](https://raspberrypi.dk/en/product/rs485-can-hat-for-raspberry-pi/) to enable RS485 communication from the Pi and I've been modifying the [demo code](https://www.jianguoyun.com/p/DTxr8-EQpdSrBxi0irsB#file=%2FSoftware%2FTest%20Codes%2FMODBUS%2Frtumaster.py::size=3219) *(Software/Test Codes/MODBUS/rtumaster.py)* and have been using a [slave simulator](http://www.simplymodbus.ca/RTUslave.htm) on my computer to test.

I'm reaching out because I've gotten stuck on trying to read data from my slave. The command seems to go through okay *(or the slave simulator doesn't complain is perhaps better to say)*, but I don't know how to get the data into my program. I've been trying something like this:

```
read = logger.info(master.execute(1, cst.READ_INPUT_REGISTERS, 5, 1))
```

And then trying to print that value to check, but it just returns 'None' instead of my value.
Any help is appreciated.

**Current code:**

```
## To install dependencies:
## sudo pip3 install modbus-tk
##################################################################################################
import serial
import fcntl
import os
import struct
import termios
import array
#import modbus lib
import modbus_tk
import modbus_tk.defines as cst
import modbus_tk.modbus as modbus
#import modbus_tk.modbus_rtu as modbus_rtu
from modbus_tk import modbus_rtu

# RS485 ioctls define
TIOCGRS485 = 0x542E
TIOCSRS485 = 0x542F
SER_RS485_ENABLED = 0b00000001
SER_RS485_RTS_ON_SEND = 0b00000010
SER_RS485_RTS_AFTER_SEND = 0b00000100
SER_RS485_RX_DURING_TX = 0b00010000
# rs 485 port
ser1 = serial.Serial("/dev/ttySC0",19200)    
ser2 = serial.Serial("/dev/ttySC1",9600)

def rs485_enable():
    buf = array.array('i', [0] * 8) # flags, delaytx, delayrx, padding
    #enable 485 chanel 1
    fcntl.ioctl(ser1, TIOCGRS485, buf)
    buf[0] |=  SER_RS485_ENABLED|SER_RS485_RTS_AFTER_SEND
    buf[1]  = 0
    buf[2]  = 0
    fcntl.ioctl(ser1, TIOCSRS485, buf)

    #enable 485 chanel 2
    fcntl.ioctl(ser2, TIOCGRS485, buf)
    buf[0] |=  SER_RS485_ENABLED|SER_RS485_RTS_AFTER_SEND
    buf[1]  = 0
    buf[2]  = 0
    fcntl.ioctl(ser2, TIOCSRS485, buf)
#end of rs485_enable():


if __name__ == '__main__':

    logger = modbus_tk.utils.create_logger("console")

    rs485_enable()

    #set modbus master
    master = modbus_rtu.RtuMaster(
           serial.Serial(port= '/dev/ttySC0',
           baudrate=9600,
           bytesize=8,
           parity='N',
           stopbits=1,
           xonxoff=0)
       )

    master.set_timeout(5.0)
    master.set_verbose(True)
    logger.info("connected")

    read = logger.info(master.execute(1, cst.READ_INPUT_REGISTERS, 5, 1))
    print("Value is: ", read)
```

Comment: Did you tried to get data from modbus simulator?

Comment: What do you mean? Like configuring the Pi to be a slave and then sending data from PC to Pi?